# Spaces in android:name in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, cordova, google-play, android-manifest

From the documentation on google play I learned that the `android:name` is also important when searching for and application. My application is called "Bike Dice", but will only appear when searched as "BikeDice", which is the name in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I tried changing it to "Bike Dice", which breaks the code and the application crashes on launch, but when I tried updating it like that in google play, I found out that it appears first when searching for "Bike Dice".

So my question is: Is there a hack or something, that allows you to have two words as `android:name`?

EDIT: Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:versionCode="102" android:versionName="0.1.2" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.dice.bike" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="BikeDice" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to this official reference please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that your manifest already has an attribute called `android:label` which was automatically generated.

```
    android:name="BikeDice"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

So you just need to select the `res/values/string.xml` file and replace the content of `app_name` with `Bike Dice` within the `<resources>` set of tags

```
    <string name="app_name">Bike Dice</string>
```

Right now, it may just be saying BikeDice, because that's probably what you specified as an application name when you first used the `new Android Project` wizard.

Comment: This sounds great! Would you please help me out with this? Not really good with xml...
I know you probably don't have enough time to teach everybody like me, so a link to a lesson would work fine ;)

Comment: Well, problem is app still crashes. I am not talking about the android:label, but about the android:name. Are you sure it can contain 2 words, even though I am using it like @srting/android_name?

Comment: Do not use two words for android:name. Use android:label for that, that's what the google store search engine will index on. I've made that experiment myself. I've even emailed the following developer to correct his manifest https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect (but he obviously hasn't followed my advice yet, because you can't find his app by just typing "Dev Apps Direct", which is a shame, his app is really a good one and he's losing traffic by not doing this).

Comment: My android label is "B.I.K.E. DICE", which is what is written under the icon. App is not appearing by searching "B.I.K.E. DICE" in google play. When I change android:name though, app is displaying first in results, but is not working at all (crashes on start)

Comment: Then, you're asking for trouble by using "." You could try escaping them in the string.xml file, but my advice would be to use BIKE DICE (or Bike Dice) instead in the label (and only use one word in the name). Auto-completion only starts working after 2 or 3 letters anyway, and the google store will probably think each letter in the label separated by a period is its own separate word (which will create all kinds of problems for you).

Comment: Will it work all fine if I just escape them? I kind of like the look. And how do I escape them? Wherever I search, there is no escape for "."

Comment: There should be a way to escape the dot, but I really really wouldn't advise you to do that. Again, that's just asking for trouble. If you want your app to be indexed correctly, you really do have to follow standard conventions. Not doing so is just asking for trouble.